# PHP form organizing post data in arrays

Tags: php, forms, multidimensional-array, submit

I have a form.

Whole div.wrap-all can be duplicated using jquery inside the form.

Also, input.foo can be duplicated inside div.wrap-subtitle

How could I get form data separated in arrays so every div.wrap-all has data in separated array?

Here is an example (very simplified):

```
<form>
    <div class="wrap-all">
        <input type="text" name="question[]">
        <div class="wrap-subtitle">
            <input class="foo" type="text" name="subtitle[]">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type=submit>
</form>
```

Here is an example how it may look like before submit:

```
<form>
    <div class="wrap-all">
        <input type="text" name="question[]">
        <div class="wrap-subtitle">
            <input class="foo" type="text" name="subtitle[]">
            <input class="foo" type="text" name="subtitle[]">
            <input class="foo" type="text" name="subtitle[]">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-all">
        <input type="text" name="question[]">
        <div class="wrap-subtitle">
            <input class="foo" type="text" name="subtitle[]">
            <input class="foo" type="text" name="subtitle[]">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type=submit>
</form>
```

Comment: `<from>` if that's a typo, you would need to update your post. It should read as `<form>`. Some may even post answers for it.

Answer (score 0):

I know a way for multidimensional arrays in html. Here is a sample.

```
<form action="" method=post>
   <input type="text" name="field[step1][]">
   <input class="foo" type="text" name="field[step2][]">
   <input type=submit>
</form>
```

Results for `print_r($_POST);` in PHP.

```
Array
(
    [field] => Array
        (
            [step1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [step2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Still doesnt answer how to get form data separated in arrays so every div.wrap-all has data in separated array?

Comment: if you are asking for jQuery you can't do that with jQuery functions. Here is an idea about that https://codepen.io/alexweissman/pen/MyWZdN